# Tutorials on Core netty and Protobuf

Tags: jakarta-ee, netty, protocol-buffers, distributed-system

I am working distributed systems(Java/EE,netty,protobuf).Wondering how to send a document  from client to server and store it in server database.

Sending string seems to be simple, but how do I go about sending a big file. Do I need to chunk into small messages and send over.

Any good tutorials, on how to work with documents.

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you've done with boilerplate code portion of netty, you have a running server with protocol buffers interceptors set and you've generated your protocol buffers related classes. If you need help with these steps, please say so, I will edit and add them.

First thing first, serialising big chunks of data (anything that may temper with heap) is no good with protobuf. Simple thing(s) to do;

1- Get the byte stream (buffered) of the content
2- Construct a protobuf message (ex: ContentChunk) and add minimum 2 fields representing the chunk order and chunk part (Depending on your concurrent traffic, your chunk parts should not crack up heap so optimise the size wisely) itself. Chunk order will help server side to reconstruct the chunk in the right order.
3- You can add an additional field for inner framing of the chunks or pass the total length in the first message.
4- Finally implement an outer framing for the main protocol message. Get the chunks and form the final Content and persist it.

For the 4th item, check Netty's current framing support.

ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder
ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender

Your pipeline should be like;

```
        bootstrap.setPipelineFactory (new ChannelPipelineFactory () {
        @Override
        public ChannelPipeline getPipeline () throws Exception {
            ChannelPipeline pipeline = Channels.pipeline ();
            pipeline.addLast ("frameDecoder", new ProtobufVarint32FrameDecoder ());
            pipeline.addLast ("protobufDecoder", new ProtobufDecoder (YOURPROTOCOL.ProtocolMessage.getDefaultInstance ()));

            pipeline.addLast ("frameEncoder", new ProtobufVarint32LengthFieldPrepender ());
            pipeline.addLast ("protobufEncoder", new ProtobufEncoder ());

            pipeline.addLast ("handler", new ClientEventHandler ());
            return pipeline;
        }
    });
```